# How to update user image secure in REST API

Tags: php, mysql, rest

I've been learning REST API for couple months for my applications.
I built a project which have login, register, reset password, change password.
But I have a logic trouble at updating user image.

For example; when I change the user password I use this;
**`/api/user/updatePassword/{email}/{token}/{password}`**

I validate code(token) from email. If its true and token not expired, I change!
***(By the way token is the code that I send to user, not token actually)***

But I don't have an option in user photo. When user use backend like;
`"change the user photo which has this e-mail"` may occur security problems as API.

How can I get through this and what is the best practice?

*(I use PHP Slim framework and MySQL)*

Comment: Don't pass password parameters or tokens in your URL query string! They end up showing up in logs, and can be a VERY BAD thing.

Comment: I will modify them as body, just leaved now for fast trying. As posting body is okey?

Comment: validated access tokens are normally sent in the headers, as they're not specific to the data being sent in any particular request. For usernames and passwords, where you're trying to request a token, yes sending them in the body makes sense, as they're data which is particular to the authentication request.

Comment: POST body/Headers are fine. That's the preferred way.

Comment: Thank you for warning. Token is not actually token by the way. Its the code I send user and keep it hashed in my database.

Comment: I see, so it's specific to the password reset action, in which case yes it belongs in the body with the other parameters.

Comment: Do you have any practice the thing that I've posted?

Comment: Well pretty much any other action which requires the user to authenticate, you would normally expect them to send an access token in the header  - they should have received this token as a result of a recent authentication request. Normally such access tokens are time-limited, and sometimes refreshable without re-authenticating, depending on the circumstances. Personally I wouldn't attempt to implement that kind of thing yourself - use an established OAuth2 library to help you, for instance. Anyway, that way you can verify who is sending the request, and whether they're authorised to do so.